# Typescript / React: Property 'children' is missing in type with function statement

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React component that takes children.

Getting a Typescript error:

`Property 'children' is missing in type ... but required in type 'FixedWidthLayout'`

That component is defined like a function statement.

`export default function FixedWidthLayout { ... }`

I don't want to write it like and expression..

i.e.

`export const FixedWidthLayout = () => {...}`

Therefore doing something like ...

`const FixedWidthLayout: React.FC<Props> = () => {...}`

..is not an option.

How is it possible to make this work with in Typescript with a function statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `React.PropsWithChildren`, which will take a type argument for the props that you want to pass to the component other than the `children`. The return type for the component can be `React.ReactNode`.

```js
interface IProps {
  // props you want to pass to the component other than the children
}

export default function FixedWidthLayout(props: React.PropsWithChildren<IProps>): React.ReactNode {

  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
      {/*The jsx code for the component*/}
    </div>
  )

}
```

Comment: If you don't care to type the other props, this works `React.PropsWithChildren<any>`.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting the error?

This should just work:

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface Props {
  children: React.Node;
}

export default function FixedWidthLayout(props: Props): JSX.Element {
  /* ... */
}

<FixedWidthLayout>Hello</FixedWidthLayout>
```